# Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker eonasdan linked inputs set max date

Tags: jquery, plugins, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

im using the Plugin Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker from eonasdan
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I have two linked inputs, the second one (#time_to) should be select up to 90 days from the date of the first input. But the maxDate starts at the current Date.
For example:

**Today:** 11. Nov 2015

**First:** 01. Jan 2016

**Second:** max. to 08. Feb 2016 *(11. Nov 2015 - 08. Feb 2016 = 90)*
should be ~ 01. April 2016

```
$('#time_from').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'de',
    viewMode: 'days',
    minDate: DateRange(0), //Current
    format: 'DD. MMMM YYYY - HH:mm',
});

$('#time_to').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'de',
    viewMode: 'days',
    maxDate: DateRange(90), // max. 90 days
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'DD. MMMM YYYY - HH:mm'
});

$('#time_from').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    $('#time_to').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(e.date);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood, you need "time_to" maxDate to be time_from + 90 days? In that case, you can just use moment.js which you need to include in your project anyways:

```
$('#time_from').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'days',
    minDate: new Date(), //Current
    format: 'DD. MMMM YYYY - HH:mm',
});

$('#time_to').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'days',
    maxDate: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 90),
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'DD. MMMM YYYY - HH:mm'
});

$('#time_from').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    $('#time_to').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(e.date);

    //Use moment.js here
    var m = moment(new Date(e.date));
    m.add(90, 'days');
    $('#time_to').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(m);
});
```

I have working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomtxsn7/2/)